# How can I Get My Custom Function to Execute Correctly?

Tags: python, string, function, printf, user-defined-functions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5spp.jpg)

I'm just following my teacher's example. She added that f in the body. I removed it but still got the same result. My name should appear when I run it, instead (name) appears.

Comment: The proper way to format a string would be `f"Hello, {name}"`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings. Also please post the code and the exception traceback when asking questions: [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (although for this particular one it wouldn't be necessary as the problem is immediately visible).

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the curly brackets `{ }` instead of `( )`

```
def say_hello(name):
    print(f"Hello, {name}!")

say_hello("Roxy")
```